# Ruby: 2 arrays merge to keep duplicates

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have searched the array methods and enumerable methods and not found any way to do this. How do merge two arrays into one array, discarding the unique values and keeping only the duplicates?

Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Array2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

. . .

Array_Result = [3, 4, 5, 6 ]

Comment: are the arrays unique? do you want only the items that appear in both arrays (intersection)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you want is only the items *that appear in both arrays* (this is called [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29)) - use the [`&`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) operator:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] & [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# =>  [3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Uri's answer, but this also works:

```
array1.uniq - (array1-array2)
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the OP wants to merge two arrays, then discard anything that is NOT duplicated in the resulting array.  If that's the case, I think the following will do the trick:

```
a3 = (array1 + array2)

# narrow it down to an array only the values which were duplicated
a3.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,val| 
  hash[val] += 1
  hash 
}.each_pair.select { |(val,count)| 
  count > 1 
}.map { |(val,count)| 
  val 
}
```

This removes duplicates, but the OP's example seems to indicate that as a goal.

Comment: Of course, if the OP was really just looking for intersection, then Uri's answer is definitely the most straight-forward.